# How to inner join two tables results on condition that either table has a like data

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT 'club_profile.'club_name_link','players'.'player_name_link' 
FROM club_profile 
     INNER JOIN players ON 'club_profile'.'club_name_link' 
       OR 'players'.'player_name_link' 
       LIKE '%".$category_result."%' 
LIMIT 0,10");
```

Result I got

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$category' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scoresfield\admin\post.php on line 22

Comment: &category_result is the value of the input field.

Comment: The `ON` clause should contain a relationship between columns in the two tables. You're not relating anything in `club_profile` to `players` in your query.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use single quotes for tables and columns name  .. when  necessary use backtics

```
"SELECT club_profile.club_name_link,players.player_name_link 
FROM club_profile 
     INNER JOIN players ON club_profile.club_name_link 
       OR players.player_name_link 
       LIKE concat('%','".$category_result."','%' )  
LIMIT 0,10");
```

( the use of $var is deprecated  because can permit sqlinjection
take  a look at the sql driver you are using and use parameter binding instead)

Comment: Its still giving the same response

Comment: answer  updated .. let me know